# How to remote debug an application hosted in Azure K8s Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, remote-debugging, portforwarding, jpda

**Basic background**

My Application is a Java application, My application is getting deployed in Azure cluster.
everything is good. But I want to know how to connect Eclipse debugger with the application running in Azure cluster.

In the startup script, `JPDA` port is bind with 8000 and in `dockerfile` `8000` port is exposed.

The issue is how to connect eclipse debugger with code running in Azure cluster.

> I tried to put the IP address in `Remote Java Application` connection properties `Host:` but not a success.

Need procedure, for remote debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after googling, I found one ninja technique . A technique we know as `port-forwarding`.

So basic idea is to forward a running application's port to our local system's available port.

So I found one command for port-forwarding:

> `kubectl port-forward pods/<podName> 8000:8000 -n <namespace>`

In this command, we need to know . For this, we need to know running pods in Kubernetes cluster on Azure. It means we need to connect or authenticate your local machine CLI with Azure.

> Download Azure CLI from this link and Install
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

- Now open PowerShell run command

  > `az login`
- Your default browser will open add your Azure credentials and Authenticate, so your `PowerShell` will show you following message when your `authentication` is done.

```
 
C:\Users\MachineName> az login
You have logged in. Now let us find all the subscriptions to which you have access...

[
  {
    "cloudName": "",
    "id": "",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "user": {
      "name": "",
      "type": ""
    }
  }
]
```

- Now next command to run is:

  > `az aks get-credentials --resource-group <ResourseGroupName> --name <Name of Kubernetes cluster>`
- Run Command to get running pods in a specific namespace if defined any.

  > `kubectl get pods -n <namespace>`
- Now you will have your running pods in specific namespace in Kubernetes cluster of Azure cloud.

```
NAME                         READY STATUS  RESTARTS    AGE

application-8664866df5-x4zns 2/2           Running 0   21m
```

- Time to run our initial command.

  > `kubectl port-forward pods/<application-8664866df5-x4zns> 6000:8000 -n myNameSpace`
- In the cli you will see

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:6000 -> 8000
Forwarding from [::1]:6000 -> 8000
```

Might be confused why I use 6000 port, because, my 8000  port is already in use.

Time to connect with eclipse:
Project `Right-click` > `debug` > `debug configuration` > search for `Remote Java Application`.

Set a name for the debugger like mine is **debugCluster** 
`Host`: 127.0.0.1 
`Port`: 6000

Now Apply and Press Debug button in some time you will see your debugger is connected with Instance running in Azure cluster.

[image]

Comment: how is this a secret?

Comment: I didn't get you!